# Python - Add new entries to dictionary while iterating over another dictionary

Tags: python, loops, dictionary

I want to check if there is an overlap between points in one dictionary with another. 
If there is no overlap, then create a new key in the dictionary with the value. 
I am getting an error while implementing the following code.

`RuntimeError: dictionary changed size during iteration`

```
for k1 in d1:
    for k2 in d2:
        if(overlap(k1,k2)==False):
            d2[len(d2)+1]=d1[k1]
```

Is there another way to implement this?

Edit:

```
d1 = {"file1":[2,3],"file2":[11,15]}
d2 = {1:[1,5],2:[6,10]}
```

Output:

```
d2 = {1:[1,5],2:[6,10],3:[11,15]}
```

Comment: What do you expect to happen if there is an overlap (same key in both dictionaries)? All of the answers (when posting this anyway) show you how to update one dict with another, but if any keys in the 2nd dictionary exist in the 1st, the value will be updated to hold the 2nd dict's value. Based on your question, it sounds like you _don't_ want that to happen?

Comment: Sorry, if I was not clear before. overlap() is a different function that checks if [start, end] values are intersecting. Both the dictionary keys are different format. I'm interested in the values inside the list. If [start, end] values overlap then I want to create a new key inside 2nd dictionary with values from 1st dictionary.

Answer (score 2):

I believe you are looking for `dict.update()`:

```
d1 = {'foo': 0,
      'bar': 1}

d2 = {'foo': 0,
      'bar': 1,
      'baz': 2}

d1.update(d2)
```

This results in:

```
d1 = {'foo': 0,
      'bar': 1,
      'baz': 2}
```

Edit:

```
import itertools

d1 = {"file1":[2,3],
      "file2":[11,15]}

d2 = {1:[1,5],
      2:[6,10]}

d2 = {**d2, **{max(d2.keys())+i+1: v for i, (k, v) in enumerate({k: v for k, v in d1.items() if not any(i in range(v[0], v[1]+1) for i in itertools.chain.from_iterable(range(v[0], v[1]+1) for v in d2.values()))}.items())}}
```

Produces:

```
d2 = {1: [1, 5],
      2: [6, 10],
      3: [11, 15]}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to merge dictionaries then the faster way is using one of these

```
a = dict(one=1,two=2,three=3,four=4,five=5,six=6)
b = dict(one=1,two=2,three=5,six=6, seven=7, nine=9)
a.update(b)
```

Which gives `{'one': 1, 'two': 2, 'three': 5, 'four': 4, 'five': 5, 'six': 6, 'seven': 7, 'nine': 9}`

Or you can use `c = dict(a, **b)`

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a double loop there. Loop through the keys in d1. Check if d2.keys contains k1. If not, add k1 to d2. I don't have the syntax right here, but something along these lines.

```
for k1 in d1.keys:
    if not k1 in d2.keys:
        d2[k1] = d1[k1]

return d2
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on your description, edit, and comments it doesn't sound like `dict.update()` will give you the results you want.

The error you're hitting is because the loop makes an assumption of the number of items it will be iterating once it starts up. During the loop, you change that number, invalidating the assumption, causing the the program to fail.

To fix this, you need to iterate a *copy* of the items instead. You also mentioned you're concerned with the values and not the keys, so you need to adjust *what* you're iterating as well.

Now, you didn't actually post what your `overlap` function does, so I'm assuming something like this based on your comments/sample:

```
def overlap(left, right):
    return left[0] - right[-1] == 1
```

For the most part, the actual implementation of your `overlap` is irrelevant to the question, but the code above at least gave me your expected output.

I've then adjusted your code to the following:

```
for v1 in list(d1.values()):
    for v2 in list(d2.values()):
        # If v1 overlaps v2
        if overlap(v1, v2):
            # Add v1 to d2 under the next sequential key
            d2[len(d1) + 1] = v1
```

By using `list(d1.values())`, I'm no longer iterating the dictionary itself while modifying it - I'm taking a "snapshot" of the contents (the values specifically here) at the start of the loop.

Using this and your sample data, `d2` contains `{1: [1, 5], 2: [6, 10], 3: [11, 15]}` after the loop.